# Not getting proper json in server while sending from java app

Tags: java, node.js, json, post

i am sendng json from a java app to a node js server but in server it only showing the key not the value of json. i am getting proper response but it is  not parsing properly. This is my java code when i am sending json to node server and server code

```
httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
         httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
         httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
         httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
         httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
         httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            OutputStreamWriter writer=new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8");
            JSONObject student1 = new JSONObject();
           JSONObject map = new JSONObject();
           map.put("name", "abc");
            writer.write(map.toString());
            System.out.println(map.toString());
            writer.close();
```

this is server code

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var mysql=require('mysql');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/',urlencodedParser,function(req,res)
{
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
console.log(req.body);

res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: '1' }));
});
app.listen(8080,'127.0.0.1');
console.log('Now listening to port 8080');
```

when i print map.toString() in java it shows proper json like

```
 {"name","abc"}
```

but in server it is showing it as

```
{ '{"name":"abc"}': '' }
```

If anyone find any solution to it please reply !!

Answer (score 1):

Please modify to this :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", "abc");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Output :

```
{"name":"abc"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error
add

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; 
charset=UTF-8");
```